# how to install TightVnc via remote command prompt‎

Tags: rdp, vnc

How can I install TightVnc via remote command prompt‎? 
I'm running windows 2003 
and I dont have any access in my rdp .

Answer (score 1):

You could use Gencontrol (free one-shot VNC utility) to get on that box and then install from the GUI.

You could also attempt to open up the TightVNC executable to see if it's run by a .msi file.  That should enable you to run your install remotely via PSExec.

-Waldo